# Creating a registration page in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Hi guys so im creating this registration page for my website in php..This is the PHP script

```
 # Script 9.5 - register.php #2
// This script performs an INSERT query to add a record to the users table.


$page_title = 'Register';
include ('includes/header.html');

// Check for form submission:
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

$errors = array(); // Initialize an error array.

// Check for a name:
if (empty($_POST['name'])) {
    $errors[] = 'You forgot to enter your name.';
} else {
    $n = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbh, trim($_POST['name']));
}

// Check for an email:
if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $errors[] = 'You forgot to enter your email.';
} else {
    $e = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbh, trim($_POST['email']));
}

// Check for a password and match against the confirmed password:
if (!empty($_POST['pass1'])) {
    if ($_POST['pass1'] != $_POST['pass2']) {
        $errors[] = 'Your password did not match the confirmed password.';
    } else {
        $p = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbh, trim($_POST['pass1']));
    }
} else {
    $errors[] = 'You forgot to enter your password.';
}

// Check for contact number:
if (empty($_POST['contact_no'])) {
    $errors[] = 'You forgot to enter your contact no.';
} else {
    $cn = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbh, trim($_POST['contact_no']));
}

if (empty($errors)) { // If everything's OK.

        require 'connect_db.php';
        $conn= mysqli_connect('*****' , '*****', '*****' , '*****' ,****);


    // Make the query:
    $q = ("INSERT INTO register_user(name, email, pass, contact_no) VALUES ('$n', '$e','$p','$cn')");       
    $r = @mysqli_query ($dbh, $q);// Run the query.
    if ($r) { // If it ran OK.

        // Print a message:
        echo '<h1>Thank you!</h1>
    <p>You are now registered. </p>
    <p><a href = "index.php">Login</a> </p>';   

    } else { // If it did not run OK.

        // Public message:
        echo '<h1>System Error</h1>
        <p class="error">You could not be registered due to a system error. We apologize for any inconvenience.</p>'; 

        // Debugging message:
        echo '<p>' . mysqli_error($dbh) . '<br/><br/> Query: ' . $q . '</p>';

    } // End of if ($r) IF.

    mysqli_close($dbh); // Close the database connection.

    // Include the footer and quit the script:
    include ('includes/footer.html'); 
    exit();

} else { // Report the errors.

    echo '<h1>Error!</h1>
    <p class="error">The following error(s) occurred:<br>';
    foreach ($errors as $msg) { // Print each error.
        echo " - $msg<br>";
    }
    echo 'Please try again.</p>';

} // End of if (empty($errors)) IF.

mysqli_close($dbh); // Close the database connection.
```

But the thing is once i register this is the output:

```
System Error

 You could not be registered due to a system error. We apologize for any inconvenience.

 Query: INSERT INTO register_user(name, email, pass, contact_no) VALUES ('', '','','')
```

so im kindly would glad for any assistance

Comment: there could be many reasons. try to var_dump your query first. enclose your column names in ``

Comment: Remove the `@` sign at here: ` $r = @mysqli_query ($dbh, $q);` and add `error_reporting(E_ALL);`  and `display_errors(1);` at the start of your file first.

Comment: And you says: `if (empty($_POST['email'])` and if not, (it could be also 1-n spaces, you trim that, so in this case `$e` will be empty.

Comment: space between table name and columns.

Comment: You're trying to connect to DB using functions that require to first be connected. Move `require 'connect_db.php';
        $conn= mysqli_connect('*****' , '*****', '*****' , '*****' ,****);` to the top of your code.

Comment: You're also using the wrong DB connection variable. `$conn` and `$dbh`

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `mysqli_real_escape_string()` **BEFORE** you establish your DB connection. This is not permitted. You **MUST** have a connection before doing the escape operations.

That means every single one of your form fields is going to be a boolean FALSE value, which signifies failure.

Your code should be structured

```
1. connect to db
2. process form inputs
3. if form inputs ok, insert into db
```

You've got #1 and #2 reversed.

Comment: Here I was ready to put in an answer "based" on my comments. Guess I'll just scrap it. Remember to mention about the wrong DB connection variable too (dot the i's and cross the t's) ;) Least this will save me the trouble.

Comment: I was going to change my mind about putting one in, but based on the OP's other questions, I am not going to fall into "that" can of worms. Btw Marc, `$conn != $dbh`

Comment: true 'nuff. sounds like OP doesn't know PHP at all (or just barely) and is just grabbing code from anywhere.

Comment: Seems like it. Oh well, OP's got enough to get him/her started. If that doesn't make it kick into gear, then may the Lord have mercy on our souls.

Comment: ...not to mention [**getting bad/wrong advice**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26121375/) from his [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26120357/); like that helps the cause. It's PDO, *hello.*